# Displaying information served on the client

Tags: javascript, interview-questions, angular.js

I recently did a coding problem for an interview that I unfortunately did not receive the position. So I figured I'd get the code reviewed by other professionals because after asking about the problems with the code I got stonewalled by the organization.

The problem is just serving from an API endpoint using Angular and displaying what's served on the client. All of it is in JavaScript and is served using a Grunt server.

**index.html**

```
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="indiegogoApp">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">indiegogo</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li ui-sref-active="home"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
              <li ui-sref-active="about"><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
              <li style="margin-top: 10px;"></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/apiservice.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/filters/tagorname.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <input class="i-text-field" id="filter" name="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchText">

  <div ng-class="appropriate_columns(filteredCards.length)">

    <div ng-repeat="card in filteredCards = (cards  | tagOrName: searchText)" class="project-card-with-friend-list" data-id={{card.id}}>
      <div class="i-project-card ">
        <a ng-href="https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/{{ card.category.name }}" class="i-category-header">
          <span class="i-icon i-category-icon i-glyph-icon-22-technology"></span>
          <span>{{ card.category.name }}</span>
        </a>
        <a ng-href="https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/{{ card.slug }}" class="i-project">
          <img ng-src="{{ card.baseball_card_image_url }}">
          <div class="i-content">
            <div class="i-title" style="word-wrap: break-word;">{{ card.title }}</div>
            <div class="i-tagline " style="max-height: 90px; word-wrap: break-word;"> {{ card.tagline }}</div>
          </div>

          <div class="i-stats">
            <span class="currency currency-medium"><span>{{card.currency.symbol}}{{ card.collected_funds }}</span><em>{{card.currency.iso_code}}</em></span>
            <div class="i-progress-bar">
              <div class="i-complete" ng-style="{ width: progress_funding_percentage(card) + '%' }"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="i-bottom-row">
              <div class="i-percent">
                {{ funding_percentage(card) }}%
              </div>
              <div class="i-time-left">
                {{ days_left(card.funding_ends_at) }} days left
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a></div>

      <div style="height: 5px;"></div>

    </div>

    <p ng-hide="filteredCards.length">Sorry, there is no result</p>

  </div>


</div>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name indiegogoApp
 * @description
 * # indiegogoApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('indiegogoApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router'
  ]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "../views/main.html",
        resolve: {
          cards: function(apiService){
             return apiService.getCards();
          }
        },
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: "../views/about.html"
      })

  });
```

**mainController.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name indiegogoApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the indiegogoApp
 */
angular.module('indiegogoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'cards', function ($scope, cards) {
    $scope.cards = cards.data.response;
    $scope.days_left = function(toDate){
      var today = new Date();
      var endDate = new Date(toDate);
      var millisecondsInDay = 86400000;
      return Math.round(Math.abs(today - endDate)/millisecondsInDay);
    };

    $scope.funding_percentage = function(card){
      return Math.round((card.collected_funds / card.goal) * 100);
    };

    $scope.progress_funding_percentage = function(card){
      var percent = $scope.funding_percentage(card);
      if(percent > 100)
       return 100;
      else
        return percent;
    };

    $scope.appropriate_columns = function(number){
      switch(number) {
        case 1:
          return 'onecol';
        case 2:
          return 'twocol';
        default:
          return 'threecol';
      }
    }
  }]);
```

**apiservice.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name indiegogoApp.apiService
 * @description
 * # apiService
 * Service in the indiegogoApp.
 */
angular.module('indiegogoApp')
  .service('apiService', function ($http) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    function getCards(){
       return $http.get('https://api.indiegogo.com/1/campaigns.json?api_token=e377270bf1e9121da34cb6dff0e8af52a03296766a8e955c19f62f593651b346').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // this callback will be called asynchronously
          // when the response is available
          return data.response;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
          return data.response;
        });
    };

    return {
      getCards: getCards
    };
  });
```

**tagOrNameFilter.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc filter
 * @name indiegogoApp.filter:tagOrName
 * @function
 * @description
 * # tagOrName
 * Filter in the indiegogoApp.
 */
angular.module('indiegogoApp')
  .filter('tagOrName', function () {
    return function (cards, input) {

      if(input == "" || input == undefined || input == null)
       return cards;

      var retVal = [];
      _.forEach(cards, function(card) {

        if(card.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase())> -1 || card.tagline.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase())> -1)
        {
          retVal.push(card);
        }
      });

      return retVal;
    };
  });
```

---

**Tests:**

**mainControllerSpec.js**

```
    'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('indiegogoApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      cards: {data: { response: [{"id":1117967,"slug":"quell-the-world-s-first-pain-relief-wearable","created_at":"2015-02-03T12:59:31-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T21:23:13-08:00","title":"Quell: The World's First Pain Relief Wearable","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1423610380/ozglhsjimrypunug0j4k.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1423610380/ozglhsjimrypunug0j4k.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1423610380/ozglhsjimrypunug0j4k.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1423610380/ozglhsjimrypunug0j4k.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1423610380/ozglhsjimrypunug0j4k.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":199052,"goal":100000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-04-01T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-03-02T02:55:48-08:00","tagline":"Quell. The first pain relief wearable. Let us help you regain what chronic pain has taken from you.","funding_days":30,"funding_type":"flexible","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1423610380/ozglhsjimrypunug0j4k.jpg","region_code":"STTE_USMA","region":"Massachusetts","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"Estados Unidos","city":"Boston","contributions_count":945,"comments_count":14,"updates_count":1,"category":{"id":27,"name":"Technology","text":"Technology"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1155310,"slug":"powersound-32hrs-music-powerbank-by-echo","created_at":"2015-02-26T05:21:36-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T21:12:00-08:00","title":"PowerSound: 32hrs Music PowerBank by Echo","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1424957355/ulm8yyswmsf4lnogybua.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1424957355/ulm8yyswmsf4lnogybua.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1424957355/ulm8yyswmsf4lnogybua.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1424957355/ulm8yyswmsf4lnogybua.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1424957355/ulm8yyswmsf4lnogybua.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":7954,"goal":10000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-03-28T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-02-26T08:43:28-08:00","tagline":"Bring Mobile & Music to life with this 32hr bluetooth playback + 5200mAh USB power bank.","funding_days":30,"funding_type":"flexible","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1424957355/ulm8yyswmsf4lnogybua.jpg","region_code":null,"region":"","country_code_alpha_2":"GB","country":"United Kingdom","city":"London","contributions_count":136,"comments_count":0,"updates_count":2,"category":{"id":27,"name":"Technology","text":"Technology"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1135339,"slug":"rocketbook-the-paper-notebook-made-for-the-cloud","created_at":"2015-02-13T10:44:23-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T21:23:16-08:00","title":"Rocketbook: The Paper Notebook Made for the Cloud","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425501630/gxmfloydljcyvbpmaodx.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425501630/gxmfloydljcyvbpmaodx.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1425501630/gxmfloydljcyvbpmaodx.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1425501630/gxmfloydljcyvbpmaodx.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1425501630/gxmfloydljcyvbpmaodx.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":5661,"goal":20000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-04-03T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-03-04T15:50:28-08:00","tagline":"Simplicity of a traditional notebook. Reusable. Cloud Integrated.","funding_days":30,"funding_type":"flexible","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1425501630/gxmfloydljcyvbpmaodx.jpg","region_code":"STTE_USMA","region":"Massachusetts","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"Estados Unidos","city":"Cambridge","contributions_count":26,"comments_count":2,"updates_count":0,"category":{"id":27,"name":"Technology","text":"Technology"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1098719,"slug":"my-purpose-my-dream","created_at":"2015-01-21T13:21:29-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T20:44:13-08:00","title":"My Purpose, My Dream","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425205310/gojmarg0ryb2ngedygwv.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425205310/gojmarg0ryb2ngedygwv.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1425205310/gojmarg0ryb2ngedygwv.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1425205310/gojmarg0ryb2ngedygwv.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1425205310/gojmarg0ryb2ngedygwv.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":11255,"goal":1500,"funding_ends_at":"2015-04-24T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-02-23T22:24:33-08:00","tagline":"Help an award-winning artist spread commercially appealing hip-hop with a message to the masses","funding_days":35,"funding_type":"flexible","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1425205310/gojmarg0ryb2ngedygwv.jpg","region_code":"STTE_USMD","region":"Maryland","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"Estados Unidos","city":"Baltimore","contributions_count":84,"comments_count":8,"updates_count":4,"category":{"id":11,"name":"Music","text":"Music"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1108560,"slug":"friends-of-the-apparating-library","created_at":"2015-01-28T07:57:34-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T21:10:41-08:00","title":"Friends of the Apparating Library","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425308941/lzedz5wntxzop0zs80aj.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425308941/lzedz5wntxzop0zs80aj.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1425308941/lzedz5wntxzop0zs80aj.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1425308941/lzedz5wntxzop0zs80aj.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1425308941/lzedz5wntxzop0zs80aj.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":10755,"goal":15000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-03-21T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-03-02T08:48:18-08:00","tagline":"Your support of this campaign will put books into the hands of people who need them.","funding_days":18,"funding_type":"flexible","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1425308941/lzedz5wntxzop0zs80aj.jpg","region_code":"STTE_USRI","region":"Rhode Island","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"United States","city":"Hogwarts","contributions_count":311,"comments_count":5,"updates_count":0,"category":{"id":19,"name":"Education","text":"Education"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1117495,"slug":"eleven-michael-tolcher-s-album-endeavor","created_at":"2015-02-03T08:33:45-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T21:09:48-08:00","title":"Eleven: Michael Tolcher's Album Endeavor","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1422981486/ltibafoxuqpaoewtiarc.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1422981486/ltibafoxuqpaoewtiarc.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1422981486/ltibafoxuqpaoewtiarc.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1422981486/ltibafoxuqpaoewtiarc.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1422981486/ltibafoxuqpaoewtiarc.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":4790,"goal":20000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-04-03T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-03-04T10:40:16-08:00","tagline":"It's been 11 years since the release of my debut album 'I Am.' It's time for 11 new songs & more!","funding_days":30,"funding_type":"fixed","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1422981486/ltibafoxuqpaoewtiarc.jpg","region_code":"STTE_USGA","region":"Georgia","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"United States","city":"Atlanta","contributions_count":75,"comments_count":3,"updates_count":0,"category":{"id":11,"name":"Music","text":"Music"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1097599,"slug":"switchmate-smart-lighting-made-simple","created_at":"2015-01-20T17:45:02-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T21:18:40-08:00","title":"Switchmate - smart lighting made simple","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1424907051/owoyjzijkvul9ooxr6in.png","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1424907051/owoyjzijkvul9ooxr6in.png","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1424907051/owoyjzijkvul9ooxr6in.png","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1424907051/owoyjzijkvul9ooxr6in.png","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1424907051/owoyjzijkvul9ooxr6in.png"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":60208,"goal":50000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-04-01T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-03-02T07:52:23-08:00","tagline":"Smart lighting with a snap!","funding_days":30,"funding_type":"fixed","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1424907051/owoyjzijkvul9ooxr6in.png","region_code":"STTE_USCA","region":"California","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"United States","city":"Palo Alto","contributions_count":723,"comments_count":56,"updates_count":1,"category":{"id":27,"name":"Technology","text":"Technology"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1158322,"slug":"cloudsolar-own-solar-panels-no-roof-required--4","created_at":"2015-02-28T06:57:10-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T21:13:54-08:00","title":"CloudSolar: Own solar panels, no roof required","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425505767/dkxmdnxmpankph4bd8kd.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425505767/dkxmdnxmpankph4bd8kd.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1425505767/dkxmdnxmpankph4bd8kd.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1425505767/dkxmdnxmpankph4bd8kd.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1425505767/dkxmdnxmpankph4bd8kd.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":92961,"goal":300000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-04-03T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-03-04T05:16:16-08:00","tagline":"No roof? No problem. Become a solar panel owner and enjoy solar no matter where you live.","funding_days":30,"funding_type":"flexible","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1425505767/dkxmdnxmpankph4bd8kd.jpg","region_code":"STTE_USMA","region":"Massachusetts","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"United States","city":"Boston","contributions_count":74,"comments_count":5,"updates_count":0,"category":{"id":20,"name":"Environment","text":"Environment"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false},{"id":1116756,"slug":"max-and-aimee","created_at":"2015-02-02T22:00:33-08:00","updated_at":"2015-03-04T20:44:38-08:00","title":"Max and Aimee","image_types":{"baseball_card":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425457540/l2komlztwofbe6wj1xec.jpg","small":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_standard/v1425457540/l2komlztwofbe6wj1xec.jpg","medium":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina/v1425457540/l2komlztwofbe6wj1xec.jpg","large":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/t_iPhone_retina_hd_v1/v1425457540/l2komlztwofbe6wj1xec.jpg","original":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/v1425457540/l2komlztwofbe6wj1xec.jpg"},"currency":{"iso_num":840,"iso_code":"USD","symbol":"$"},"collected_funds":4400,"goal":6000,"funding_ends_at":"2015-03-26T23:59:59-07:00","funding_started_at":"2015-02-24T12:02:46-08:00","tagline":"A drama about a man's struggle with dementia and his last connection with his daughter.","funding_days":30,"funding_type":"flexible","baseball_card_image_url":"http://res.cloudinary.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,h_220,w_220/v1425457540/l2komlztwofbe6wj1xec.jpg","region_code":"STTE_USCA","region":"California","country_code_alpha_2":"US","country":"Estados Unidos","city":"San Francisco","contributions_count":65,"comments_count":2,"updates_count":0,"category":{"id":9,"name":"Film","text":"Film"},"forever_funding_active":false,"perks_available":true,"stripe_payout_active":false}]} },
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of cards to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.cards.length).toBe(9);
  });

  it('should return the appropriate name for appropriate_columns', function(){
    expect(scope.appropriate_columns(1)).toBe('onecol');
    expect(scope.appropriate_columns(2)).toBe('twocol');
    expect(scope.appropriate_columns(3)).toBe('threecol');
    expect(scope.appropriate_columns(4)).toBe('threecol');
  });

  it('should return the expected amount for funding funding_percentage', function(){
    //card.collected_funds / card.goal
    var card1 = { collected_funds: 10, goal: 2 };
    var card2 = { collected_funds: 2, goal: 10};

    expect(scope.funding_percentage(card1)).toBe(500); // correctly returns when over 100
    expect(scope.funding_percentage(card2)).toBe(20); // correctly returns when under 100
  });

  it('should return 100 when over 100% for progress_funding_percentage', function(){
    var card1 = { collected_funds: 10, goal: 2 };
    var card2 = { collected_funds: 2, goal: 10};

    expect(scope.progress_funding_percentage(card1)).toBe(100); // correctly returns when over 100
    expect(scope.progress_funding_percentage(card2)).toBe(20); // correctly returns when under 100
  });

 it('should return the correct amount of days left', function(){
   expect(scope.days_left(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))).toBe(1);
   expect(scope.days_left(new Date)).toBe(0);
 });

});
```

**tagOrNameFilterSpec.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('Filter: tagOrName', function () {

  // load the filter's module
  beforeEach(module('indiegogoApp'));

  // initialize a new instance of the filter before each test
  var tagOrName;
  beforeEach(inject(function ($filter) {
    tagOrName = $filter('tagOrName');
  }));

  it('should return the matching collection items based on tagline or title"', function () {
    var text = 'angularjs';
    var collection = [{tagline: 'test', title: 'testcard'}];
    expect(tagOrName(collection, text)[0]).toBe(undefined);

    text = 'test';
    expect(tagOrName(collection, text)[0].tagline).toBe(collection[0].tagline);
    expect(tagOrName(collection, text)[0].title).toBe(collection[0].title);
  });

});
```

Comment: I wanted something to do on the train home, goodie. First thing I see though: `$scope.cards = cards.data.response;` - please don't do this. You're attempting to get the response of a promise that may, or may not, be resolved yet.  I'll do a full write up and post it at around 6.30pm GMT ish.

Please remove the Gruntfile, by the way. It's autogenerated by Yeoman and is not relevant to the question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to review your mark up too much but rather focus on the JavaScript.

## Keep controllers thin

Your controllers should be as small as possible, ideally only handling the assigning of things to a `$scope`. Your controller has quite a bit of logic in it, especially some stuff that could be shifted to a filter. For example, `$scope.days_left()` is just manipulating the way data is displayed. This could easily be changed to a filter (unless that is actually needed for your program to function, in which case it should IMO be a service).

```
module.filter('daysRemainingFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var today = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date(toDate);
    var milliseconds = 86400000;
    return Math.round(Math.abs(today - endDate)/milliseconds);
  }
});
```

Just remember that filters are executed twice every digest cycle, so keep them small also.

## Use of promises

Firstly, `$scope.cards = cards.data.response` is wrong. I said in my comment you may be resolving a promise that's not resolved - this was false because it is resolved by ui router - however you should just be doing `$scope.cards = cards`. To change this we need to look at the way you handle your `$http` call in your service.

```
return $http.get('https://api.indiegogo.com/1/campaigns.json?api_token=e377270bf1e9121da34cb6dff0e8af52a03296766a8e955c19f62f593651b346').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    return data.response;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    return data.response;
  });
```

`.success()` and `.error()` messages are syntactic sugar for `.then(success,error)`. Their return values are the things that are returned to the ui router, but **only if UI router uses `success()` and `error()` too**. Otherwise those changes are lost. UI router does not use `success()` and `error()` because those two functions are only applicable to promises returned by `$http`. As a result, I would recommend you change the above to this:

```
return $http.get('....')
  .then(function(xhr) {
    // success
    return xhr.data;
  });
```

And fill in those method bodies as necessary. Also, don't `return data.response;` you lose valuable information, especially on error, by doing this. Instead you should actually try and handle the error. You can do this by throwing an `Error` in the error handler, if you want - this should cause a `$stateChangeError` event to be emitted by UI Router, and you can react to that and display some feedback without ever hitting the faulty state. Ideally, you would handle that eventuality inside of your state code, like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "../views/main.html",
    resolve: {
      cards: function(apiService){
        return apiService.getCards()
          .then(_.identity, function(xhr) {
            throw new Error(xhr.status);
          });
      }
    },
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
```

## Controller As

This is just a recommendation but something that's been cropping up recently is the `controllerAs` syntax and it's something I use very liberally. Essentially, your controller assigns it's stuff to `this`, rather than `$scope`, and then the directive/`$state` config will invoke the controller with `new` and place the `new`-ed up value on the `$scope` as the name you used. This is done in your `$state` configuration like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    ....
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  });
```

Your code can now be changed to this

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['cards', function (cards) {
  this.cards = cards.data.response;
  this.days_left = function(toDate) {
    var today = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date(toDate);
    var millisecondsInDay = 86400000;
    return Math.round(Math.abs(today - endDate)/millisecondsInDay);
  };
  ...
```

In my opinion this provides better encapsulation and looks nicer on the eyes too. It also makes your tests easier because you don't need to worry about `$scope` past the `$compile` stage. All the values you place on `this` will then be located at `$scope.main`, so you will need to edit your mark up.

## snake_case

In JavaScript, camelCase is the standard. Don't use snake_case.

## lodash utility methods

You use

```
return function (cards, input) {

  if(input == "" || input == undefined || input == null)
   return cards;

  var retVal = [];
  _.forEach(cards, function(card) {

    if(card.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase())> -1 || card.tagline.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase())> -1)
    {
      retVal.push(card);
    }
  });

  return retVal;
};
```

This could be refactored to this:

```
return function (cards, input) {
  if(_.isEmpty(input))
    return cards;

  var loweredInput = input.toLowerCase();
  return _.filter(cards, function(card) {

    return _.contains(card.title.toLowerCase(), loweredInput) || _.contains(card.tagline.toLowerCase(), loweredInput);
  });
};
```

## API key

Your API key is hardcoded into your application - instead, make it an angular constant and inject it into the service.

## Short tests

Your tests are way too verbose. In your controller test, you hard code an *entire* card object. That is not necessary - just put in the bare minimum required.
Additionally, in your filter test, you wrap the entire object in an array, but you don't need to. Not only that, but you have three asserts in one test - this is never good.
Aim for one assert per test.

```
it('should return nothing when no items match"', function () {
  var text = 'angularjs';
  var object = {tagline: 'test', title: 'testcard'};

  expect(tagOrName([object], text)).toBe(undefined);
});

it('should return the matching collection items title"', function () {
  var object = {tagline: 'test', title: 'testcard'};

  expect(tagOrName([object], object.tagline)[0].title).toBe(object.title);
});

it('should return the matching collection items based on tagline"', function () {
  var object = {tagline: 'test', title: 'testcard'};

  expect(tagOrName([object], object.tagline)[0].tagline).toBe(object.tagline);
});
```

That's all I've got right now but I'm sure there is more. Overall not bad, but a few of the mistakes you made might have shown your inexperience a little too much. Sorry you didn't get the job, but give it a couple more months and you'll be fine :)

Comment: Bumming me out man! But thanks for showing me some love and reviewing that. I appreciate it, hopefully I can get a better gig later on! I'll just have to do more code reviews here haha!

Comment: Em ... did you mean to put `filter` as **method** in your top code example?

Comment: Yes... good catch

Comment: I'd like to add on in retrospect that it is common to use a HTTP interceptor to handle expected HTTP errors and that you MAY choose to use those instead of throwing an error in the reject promise handler. That said, you  should probably still `throw` errors you don't expect from that handler in the first place..